# Split large gz files while preserving rows

Tags: linux, bash, split, terminal, compression

I have a larger .gz file (2.1G) that I am trying to load into R, but it is large enough that I have to split it into pieces and load each individually before recombining them. However, I am having difficulty in splitting the file in a way that preserves the structure of the data. The file itself, with the exception of the first two rows, is a 56318 x 9592 matrix with non-homogenous entries.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. First, I tried using the split command from terminal as suggested by this link (https://askubuntu.com/questions/54579/how-to-split-larger-files-into-smaller-parts?rq=1)

```
$ split --lines=10000 "originalFile.gct.gz" "originalFile.gct.gz.part-"
```

Doing this, though, creates far more files than I would have expected (since my matrix has 57000 rows, I was hoping to output 6 files, each 10000 rows in size). When reading one of these into R and investigating the dimensions, I see that each is a matrix of 62x9592, indicating that the columns have all been preserved, but I'm getting significantly less rows than I would have hoped. Further, when reading it in, I get an error specifying an unexpected end of file. My thought is that it's not reading in how I want it to.

I found a two possible alternatives here - https://superuser.com/questions/381394/unix-split-a-huge-gz-file-by-line

In particular, I've tried piping different arguments using gunzip, and then passing the output through to split (with the assumption that perhaps the file being compressed is what led to inconsistent end lines). I tried

```
$ zcat originalFile.gct.gz  | split -l 10000 "originalFile.gct.gz" "originalFile.gct.gz.part-"
```

but, doing this, I ended up with the exact same splits that I had previously. I have the same problem replacing "zcat" with "gunzip -c", which should have sent the uncompressed output to the split command.

Another answer on that link suggested piping to head or tail with something like zcat, for example

```
$ zcat originalFile.gct.gz | head -n 10000 >> "originalFile.gct.gz.1"
```

With zcat, this works perfectly, and it's exactly what I want. The dimension for this ends up being 10000x9592, so this is the ideal solution. One thing that I'll note is that this output is an ASCII text file rather than a compressed file, and I'm perfectly OK with that.

However, I want to be able to do this until end up file, making an additional output file for each 10000 rows. For this particular case, it's not a huge deal to just make the six, but I have tens of files like this, some of which are >10gb. My question, then, is how can I use split command that will take the first 10000 lines of the unzipped file and then output them, automatically updating the suffix with each new file? Basically, I want the output that I got from using "head", but with "split" so that I can do it over the entire file.

Comment: When a file is compressed, the original structure of the data is not visible at all. You need to split the file before compressing it if you want it to be split logically by the data.

Comment: @Barmar the issue here is that I received these files already compressed. I'm hoping to decompress them (without changing the original file) and then split that output rather than the other way around

Comment: your first command was basically discarding the output of zcat, and split was reading the compressed data directly from the file. In your solution `-` means "read from standard input", so now split would read the data written in the pipe by zcat....

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution that ended up working for me

```
$ zcat originalFile.gct.gz | split -l 10000 - "originalFile.gtc.gz-"
```

As Guido mentioned in the comment, my original command

```
$ zcat originalFile.gct.gz | split -l 10000 "originalFile.gct.gz" "originalFile.gct.gz.part-"
```

was discarding the output of zcat, and split was once again reading from the compressed data. By including the "-" after the split argument, I was able to pass the standard output from zcat into split, and now the piping works as I was expecting it to.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to control your splitting better, you can use `awk`.
You mentioned that the first two rows were special.
Try something like

```
zcat originalFile.gct.gz | 
   awk 'BEGIN {j=1} NR<3 {next} {i++} i%5==0 {j++} {print > "originalFile.gct.part"j }'
```

When you want your outfiles compressed, modify the awk command: Let is `print` the completed files and use `xargs` to gzip them.

Answer (score 0):

If spliting based on the content of the file works for you. Try:

`zcat originalFile.gct.gz | awk -F$',' '{print $0 | "gzip > /tmp/name_"$1".gct.gz";}'`

and example line of my file was: `2014,daniel,2,1,2,3`

So I was splitting the files for the year (first column) using the

Answer (score 0):

If spliting based on the content of the file works for you. Try:

```
zcat originalFile.gct.gz | awk -F$',' '{print $0 | "gzip > /tmp/file_"$1".gct.gz";}'
```

and example line of my file was:

```
2014,daniel,2,1,2,3
```

So I was splitting the files for the year (first column) using the variable $1

Getting and ouput of:

```
/tmp/file_2014.gct.gz
/tmp/file_2015.gct.gz
/tmp/file_2016.gct.gz
/tmp/file_2017.gct.gz
/tmp/file_2018.gct.gz
```